# PowerBi authentication issue with Azure AD Oauth

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, oauth, powerbi

I am trying to authenticate my app to use PowerBi REST APIs. For this I am trying to use the example given [here](https://github.com/guyinacube/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data) for non-power BI users. Here is my code that I used for authentication. But it is giving the following exception.

*Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.*

I have made sure i have entered the correct application and group ID.

```
 var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);

        // Authenticate using created credentials
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorityUrl"]);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceUrl"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"], credential);

        if (authenticationResult == null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Authentication Failed.");

        }
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong here? My Azure user name has got owner access in this app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, however this error happens because you need to create your application in Azure. You need to set some informations like: the correct callback

Try to follow this document to create your application:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-app/